# Is $\{(x, y) : 0 \le x, y \le 1\}$ compact in the Moore plane?

Tags: general-topology

Consider $A=\{(x,y)\colon 0\leq x,y\leq 1\}$ in Moore plane,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane,

> Is $A$ a compact set?

My answer is not because $B=\{(x,0)\colon 0\leq x\leq 1\}$ is closed subset of $A$ and has discrete topology as subspace. So, $A$ can not be a compact set. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right, the whole $x$-axis is a discrete subspace. This is also essential in the proof that it's not normal.

Comment: Henno Brandsma , if we shift $A$ a bit , that is , still unite but does not tauch $x$-axis. So,  it is compact. Right?

Comment: @00GB if it lies completely in the open upper half plane it just has the Euclidean topology and will be compact.